# Views video file with attached thumbnails

Tags: views, files

The idea:
A page "Video" with one embedded youtube video and down bellow will have a small images (screenshots of videos). These images will be linked to a individual video, so when a user click one of the small images, the embedded video will change and on the same location will open the new selected video.

I guess this will be possible with the Views module. Let's say with a display page "video" and will show only one video. Down bellow maybe attached view or separated view, but I don't know what and how to display.